# Requests to the server blocked, Shopify_app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify, shopify-app

I am attempting to install my rails app following the guide for the shopify_app gem. I installed it to my dev store on shopify and then i get this screen when trying to access the app.

EDIT: I am getting this in the console:

```
Refused to frame 'https://localhost:3000/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "child-src 'self' https://* shopify-pos://*". Note that 'frame-src' was not explicitly set, so 'child-src' is used as a fallback.
```

[image]

Please help me. No clue whats happening.

EDIT: IT seems as though there is an issue loading an iFrame from an http to a https on my shopify app because when I deploy the app to heroku and do it that way the app works...

How can I make it so i can use localhost as dev until im ready to launch?

Comment: Hey there! I experience the exact same thing, but with a php app and by hosting the app on Amazon EC2 servers (Elastic Beanstalk) with load balancer and with Amazon's own SSL security certificate. The SSL certificate and all else is completely fine with https://, however Shopify does not load the app in the Iframe from https:// Here's the screenshot with the error https://screencast.com/t/VScHNcjQwf4

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to read up on using a service like forwardhq or ngrok. That way you can test and develop localhost, including webhooks, and proxy calls. Works like a peach. Shopify fully documents it, check out their suggestions.

Comment: Hi David, do you know if there is some connection to exactly the same error and hosting the app on Amazon servers with Amazon's SSL certificate... because I get the exact same error with Amazon. When the app is hosted on different server with different SSL certificate, it never produces this error... https://screencast.com/t/VScHNcjQwf4

Comment: I always make sure I use https to start my sessions... whenever I forget to use https things screw up...

Comment: Thanks for the reply... I'm a bit confused here as to what session... since the app is hosted on Amazon EC2 and their servers. I have no control there... or what session do you mean? It's a PHP app.

Comment: I mean if I am testing.. and I call up the login screen.. forgetting https is the start of problems...

Comment: I hate Ngrok with a passion because every time I run it, it generates a different URL which means basically everyday I have to change that url in app settings, in shopify partners app setup and on my device's bookmarks. Completely useless for me. I'm having the same issue as the OP with https://localhost:3000 and I suspect it has something to do with the localhost's SSL certificate.

Comment: I never have any problems with this, as I use forwardHQ, which gives me an URL I can forward to localhost.